# es mit + Substantiv

Tags: word-usage, usage

Aus einer Zeitung:

> "Es ist eine Illusion, zu glauben, dass diejenigen, die davon profitieren, **es mit** der Zusammenarbeit ernst meinen"

Ich habe die Bedeutung dieses Ausdrucks im Wörterbuch nicht gefunden. Ich nehme an, es bedeutet "das, wovon wir schon gesprochen haben", "das, was wir wissen" usw.
Kurz gesagt: "Alles, was die Zusammenarbeit betrifft, interessiert uns nicht."

Ich wollte bitte wissen, ob das richtig ist, ob dieser Ausdruck zu schriftsprachlich ist, und ob man den mit irgendeinem Substantiv verwenden kann, d. h. auch mit Personen sowie Dingen.

Zum Beispiel:

Das/es mit deinem Sohn macht mich traurig. (Ich habe gehört, dass er einen Unfall gehabt hat.)

Ich bin um das/es mit dem Job meines Nachbarn besorgt. (Man hat mir gesagt, dass er seinen Job verlieren könnte.)

Comment: I believe the expression *es ernst meinen mit x* is idiomatic and fixed as such.

Comment: Vielleicht. Aber die Tatsache ist, dass sie haben keine Ansicht zusammen zu arbeiten, weil auf diese Weise der Zustand besser für sie ist.

Comment: "Es mit deinem Sohn ..." ist kein richtiger Satz, auch nicht einer, der etwas anderes bedeutet. "Ich bin um es mit dem Job" ist noch schlimmer; auch die Alternative ist falsch: "Ich bin um den Job ... besorgt" wäre richtig.

Answer (score 6):

This is part of the phrase `es mit etwas ernst meinen` (to be serious about something).

Simplified:

> Sie meinen es ernst mit der Zusammenarbeit.
>
> They are serious about the cooperation.

Comment: In Spanish: "tomar algo en serio".

Comment: Vielleicht noch unterstreichen, dass das (es mit) nicht eng verbunden ist, wie die Umstellung des Satzes zeigt. "Ich habe es mit der Rückgabe nicht eilig", "Ich nehme es mit Humor", "habe es mit Anstand beendet".

Answer (score 1):

[Elena](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/14867/392) hat die Frage ja schon beantwortet - nur der Verständlichkeit halber möchte ich das noch ausführen.

### Zur Bedeutung des Satzes:

> Es ist eine Illusion, zu glauben, dass diejenigen, die davon profitieren, es mit der Zusammenarbeit ernst meinen"

Wer „*es mit der Zusammenarbeit ernst meint*“, der sagt: „*Ich möchte mit Dir / Ihnen zusammenarbeiten*“, und **er will auch tatsächlich zusammenarbeiten**. Wer es mit der Zusammenarbeit **nicht** ernst meint, **sagt** zwar dasselbe, **meint** es aber nicht: Er will maximal den äußeren Schein der Zusammenarbeit bei maximalem eigenen Nutzen und minimaler eigener Investition, und wenn das zu lästig wird, will er nicht einmal mehr das.

Im Ausgangssatz haben wir eine Situation, in der jemand von der Zusammenarbeit *profitiert* - und damit auch ein Interesse daran hat, den *status quo* aufrechtzuerhalten. Wer es „mit der Zusammenarbeit ernst meint“, wird auch weiter zur Zusammenarbeit bereit sein, auch wenn der Profit geringer wird.

Es ist also ungenau, den Satz zu interpretieren als: „*Alles, was die Zusammenarbeit betrifft, interessiert uns nicht*.“ Eher: „*An der Zusammenarbeit interessiert uns nur der Nutzen, den wir unmittelbar daraus ziehen. **Mehr** interessiert uns nicht - verlasst Euch also nicht darauf, dass wir auch noch morgen zusammenarbeiten wollen*“.

### Zur Verwendung mit anderen Substantiven:

Wie schon von @Cerberus kommentiert, ist die Formulierung „es ernst meinen“ ein stehender Ausdruck. Daher kann man das „es“ nicht einfach durch ein „das“ ersetzen.

Auf die beiden Beispiele bezogen: In den Sätzen „*Das/es mit deinem Sohn macht mich traurig.*“ und „*Ich bin um das/es mit dem Job meines Nachbarn besorgt.*“ kann man statt „*es*“ nicht einfach „*das*“ schreiben. „***Es*** mit deinem Sohn tut mir leid“ wäre m.E. also falsch. Auch die Formulierung „*Das mit deinem Sohn macht mich traurig*“ wird zwar oft gebraucht, aber in der Schriftsprache würde ich es nicht verwenden. Die Formulierung dient ja eher als Notbehelf, um das unangenehmer Faktum (Unfall) zu „umgehen“ und nicht aussprechen zu müssen.

Comment: Ich danke euch. Ich habe den Satz falsch verstanden, indem ich (auch falsch) angenommen habe, dass "es mit der Zusammenarbeit" so bedeutete, wie "was die Zusammenarbeit betrifft".

Comment: Die Ausführung ist weitschweifend aber nicht sachdienlich. Statt sich zum wesentlichen vorzuarbeiten und zu konzentrieren wird das Kopfkino eingeschaltet und geplaudert. Es ist im Satz gar nicht die Rede davon, dass jemand etwas gesagt hat; pure Phantasie! Dann wird ein "uns" in die Debatte eingeführt, das aus dem Nichts kommt. Die Aussage ist doch eine Warnung, dass die eine Partei es mit der Zusammenarbeit nicht ernst meint. Gesprochen wird also enteweder von der Gegenpartei, oder einer neutralen, beobachtenden Instanz (etwa der Presse).

Comment: Für die Erklärung der Floskel ist eine solch ausufernde Betrachtung kontraproduktiv. Es braucht keinen Haupt- und Nebensatz: "Wir meinen es ernst mit der Zusammenarbeit" enthält das "es ... mit" in gleicher Funktion.

Comment: Ich will betonen, dass ich die Debatte nicht gesucht habe.

Comment: Ich will betonen, dass ich die Debatte nicht gesucht habe. Jetzt ist es mir klar, dass ich den Satz falsch verstanden hatte. Ich wiederhole, dass ich angenommen hatte, dass "es mit der Zusammenarbeit" so bedeutete, wie "wass die Zusammenarbeit betrifft". Auch mir macht es nichts aus, was der Kontext des Artikels war, auch nicht die Absicht der Zusammenarbeiter ist.